# Tag Synonym is Incorrect

Tags: discussion

I don't yet have the privilege to create tag synonyms and I found a synonym which I believe to be incorrect.

Currently, the "triangulation" tag remaps to "tin".  I think this is wrong.  While the t in tin stands for triangulation, they are very different.

[Wikipedia's definition of triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation):

> In trigonometry and geometry, triangulation is the process of
>   determining the location of a point by measuring angles to it from
>   known points at either end of a fixed baseline, rather than measuring
>   distances to the point directly (trilateration). The point can then be
>   fixed as the third point of a triangle with one known side and two
>   known angles.

And the article on TIN [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_irregular_network).

Clearly, different definitions.

Here's an example of [a post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/difference-between-triangulation-and-trilateration) which I tried to tag as "triangulation".  It automatically remapped to tin which just doesn't suit.

Can we get this changed?

Comment: added trilateration tag makes it searchable on GIS-SE - it also good to understand the difference for newcomers or less experienced users on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for noticing that.

I removed the triangulation-->TIN synonym.  But this does not resolve the issue: did you notice that Wikipedia lists almost a dozen distinct meanings of "triangulation"?  The process of triangulation to create a TIN--usually Delaunay triangulation--is mentioned on our site at least as often as triangulation in a surveying context (and that was the context in which the triangulation tag had been created originally).

As a stopgap, to make the disambiguation clear, I tagged your referenced post with [triangulation-survey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangulation-survey). There must be a better name for this; I welcome suggestions.